# Filter records in a table based on some columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, exists

I have one table (say , table name is "items") as given below.

| id | timestamp | name | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 16106800 | pqr | 10 |
| 100 | 16106800 | pqr | 0 |
| 100 | 16106400 | pqr | 15 |

If there are more than one record with same name and same timestamp then I want to exclude one with zero amount. For example -  In the above table , we have two records (first and second records) with same name and same timestamp, so I have to exclude one record with zero amount.

Expected result is as below:

| id | timestamp | name | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 16106800 | pqr | 10 |
| 100 | 16106400 | pqr | 15 |

I wrote a query like below but that doesn't work completely.

```
SELECT *
FROM items w
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM items x  
    WHERE x.timestamp = w.timestamp AND x.name=w.name
) AND w.amount > 0
```

My above query getting failed when all the timestamps are different. If there is no records with same name and same timestamp then it will not exclude anything from items table.

**EDIT** : If there is only one row with zero amount in that table then it should not be excluded.

Comment: What if there is only the one `0` row for that name and timestamp?

Comment: If there is only one row it should not exclude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My query produces these results:

If you have only one record despite the amount, it is showed

If you have more than one record, it will show only the records with amount > 0

So, try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM items t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 FROM items t2
    WHERE t1.id = t2.id 
    AND t1.timestamp = t2.timestamp 
    AND t1.name = t2.name
    AND t2.amount > 0)
OR t1.amount > 0
```

See [***SQL Fiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/56b0c/1/0)

Be aware: I've written on SQL Fiddle with a different DBMS but the SQL used is standard, so it's OK for SQL Server too.

Comment: What if there is only one row with zero amount in that table ? , Could not open the SQL Fiddle link.

Comment: @user3656231 If you have only one row with amount = 0 you'll show it, as your question

Comment: So your query wll NOT exclude when there is only one record with zero amount , right? . This what I found when I tested it.

Comment: @user3656231 Dear, maybe I don't understand your request. My query does: If you have only one record (amount = 0 or amount > 0) record is showed, If you have more than one record, only record with amount > 0 are showed. This accomplish your aim?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just aggregate?

```
select id, timestamp, name, sum(amount) as amount
from items
group by id, timestamp, name;
```

This returns one row per `id`/`timestamp`/`name` combination, with the total amount for that combination.  I suspect this does what you really want.

But, you can also modify your query by tweaking the logic:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM items i
WHERE i.amount > 0 OR
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM items i2
                  WHERE i2.timestamp = i.timestamp AND
                        i2.name = i.name AND
                        i2.amount > 0
                 );
```

That is, return all rows where the `amount > 0`.  And then also return all rows for a `timestamp`/`name` combination where there is no row with an `amount > 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use `count() over()`

```
SELECT id, timestamp, name, amount
FROM (
    SELECT *, count(*) over(partition by id, timestamp, name) cnt
    FROM yourtable) t
WHERE cnt = 1 OR amount > 0
```

[db<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=aff992d549997f0d9973be11f22593cb)

Answer (score 0):

```
;with a as (
select distinct id,timestamp,name from items
),
with b as (
select * from items
where amount > 0
)
select a.id,a.timestamp,a.name,isnull(b.amount,0) amount  
from a join b on a.timestamp = b.timestamp and a.name = b.name
```

Answer (score 0):

**A conditional Window Aggregate `COUNT(CASE...) OVER...` is probably your best bet:**

```sql
SELECT id, timestamp, name, amount
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        count(case when amount > 0 then 1 end)
            over(partition by timestamp, name) CountNonZeroes
    FROM Table
) t
WHERE CountNonZeroes = 0 OR amount > 0
```